Can you sum demodulated signals with a single summing amp, or is it best to demodulate individually then sum together?
I'm working with Delta-Sigma modulation signals for audio ADC/DAC, and I'm curious if there is a best practice when it comes to summing their signals. Demodulation is generally achieved with a simple R-C LPF filter, but does each demodulated signal require its own path before summing, or can the combination be done with a single summing amplifier? I've drawn a quick example:

A single-sided supply of 5V-0V is assumed here. On the left we have the individual signals demodulated separately then summed, on the right the individual signals are both demodulated and summed in the same step. Which is preferred, or is there a difference besides parts count? Thank you!

If all the circuits are linear, then there is no conceptual difference.
There is a big difference in the circuits you have drawn, which is at the level of an oversight or mistake. The lowpass filtering on the right does not work, as the virtual ground amplifier short-circuits the 470 pF capacitor to ground.
The lowpass filters on the left provide a varying voltage back to the buffers not shown that drive the 22k resistors, depending on the history of the output voltage. This may upset mis-behaving buffers, altering their drive strength and hence damaging their linearity. For straight CMOS gate outputs, this will probably not be a problem for most purposes.
The 22ks on the right are shorted to ground at their outputs, so the buffers see a consistent 22k load regardless of signal history. This configuration will be more linear, notwithstanding the filtering doesn't work as drawn.

Thank you for that reply! For the drawing on the right would it be best to take the 470p cap to VREF instead, and/or would adding a 22K resistor between the non-inverting input and VREF help as well? I feel like when it comes to inverting amps/inverting summing amps I sometimes see a resistor to VREF (usually the same value as the summing and feedback resistors), and other times I don't, so I left it off, perhaps errantly.

@paraparabolic Chanign the amplifier configuration to a voltage buffer, as used following the filters in your left hand picture, would be the most appropriate. Note you would need to increase the cap to 1 nF to keep the same time constant as on the left, as the two 22k are in parallel as far as the signals are concerned. A resistor from +ve input to vref is used for controlling DC offsets and adding noise, neither are neccessary or desired in audio applications. It doesn't matter where you ground the cap, it's still shorted by your virtual ground amplifier input.

so both 22K resistors would go to the op amp's non-inverting input with a 1nF cap to ground, and the op amp is configured as a buffer (as it is drawn on the left), am I understanding correctly?

Just realized that using the configuration on the right but moving the cap to be in parallel with the feedback resistor should work, yes?

@paraparabolic Inband, the two types of LPF will work much the same. At HF, shortcomings in the opamp on the right would reduce the depth of the stopband. As SigmaDelta has a large amount of noise energy at high frequency, probably not a good thing to do without a very fast opamp. On the left, the opamps only need to be cooking grade.
